# Google Cloud Datastore REST API from a browser

Tags: javascript, rest, google-cloud-datastore

I search if it's possible and how calling Google Cloud Datastore REST API
from a browser with JavaScript.
I know this is possible from Node.js : 
https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs

But I don't find any example how to do that from a React.js or Angular application.

My application is not critical and I don't want to create fat Java endpoint in my back-end.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for -

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/rest/

Comment: I saw but i don't understand how to use that, where is the examples ?

Comment: The examples are lacking, but you can use their request builder which is quite intuitive: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/data/rest/v1/projects/runQuery#Value